# How to get the modified textbox value in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used a textbox in gridview to bind a value from db during pageload..
The problem is when i change the textbox value i could not get the modified value in c#, instead it gives the original value which had been there before i modified..
I am using **nested GridViews**...
kindly help me..

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Singles" >
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hidqua" runat="server" Value='<%#bind("QualityName") %>' />
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hidfau" runat="server" Value='<%#bind("FaultName") %>' />
   <asp:TextBox ID="asptxtsingleg" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("singles") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and below is my c# Coding

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "update")
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdInspection.Rows)
            {
                HiddenField hv = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hidval");
                GridView txtsi = (GridView)row.FindControl("grdInsiewChid");
                foreach (GridViewRow row1 in txtsi.Rows)
                {
                    HiddenField htn = (HiddenField)row1.FindControl("hdnPLength");
                    GridView nesgrid = (GridView)row1.FindControl("GridView1");
                    foreach (GridViewRow row2 in nesgrid.Rows)
                    {
                        HiddenField qn = (HiddenField)row2.FindControl("hidqua");
                        TextBox t = (TextBox)row2.FindControl("asptxtsingleg");

                    }
                }
            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: in which event you using this?and explain what you have actually needs

Comment: rowcommand event.. even i tried button event but same result

Comment: i need to get modified textbox value in "Textbox t"

Comment: you can use RowUpdating event to get the modified row data

Comment: mm k i try that and say the result, thank u

Comment: in RowCommand event you don't need to loop through the grid view rows again.. RowCommand is when you click on a button from your gridview then you could get the values from the selected row.

Comment: @arun, Are you using any button to fire the Rowcommand event ?

Comment: s Rowupdate command button.. actually i am using nested gridviews. so only i edited my above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using button to fire the RowCommand event.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Singles">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="asptxtsingleg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("singles") %>' Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="BtnEdit" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="updateData" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Your_ID") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "updateData")
    {
        //int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

        TextBox tb = (TextBox)row.FindControl("asptxtsingleg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the text box value in RowUpdating event

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
TextBox t= (TextBox)row.FindControl("asptxtsingleg");
```